# Aggregating sum of nested documents in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm creating a  voting application using MongoDB. I am trying to retrieve the sum of all the 'votes' (ie. votes.rating) per database-person when running a getAllPersons query in MongoDB - but am not able to make it work.

Here is an example output of my getAllPersons query

```json
[   
    {
        "_id": "63964b3f9677c609e9c81054",
        "name": "Gordie Howe",
        "img": "./assets/gordie-howe.png",
        "votes": [
            {
                "rating": 1,
                "_id": "63c08fb8f8640bf8bb683314",
                "ratingId": "63c08fb8f8640bf8bb683315",
                "createdAt": "2023-01-12T22:54:48.659Z"
            },
            {
                "rating": 1,
                "_id": "63c08fccf8640bf8bb68334e",
                "ratingId": "63c08fccf8640bf8bb68334f",
                "createdAt": "2023-01-12T22:55:08.455Z"
            },
            {
                "rating": 1,
                "_id": "63c14d5ec2101f2f38ddf941",
                "ratingId": "63c14d5ec2101f2f38ddf942",
                "createdAt": "2023-01-13T12:23:58.692Z"
            }
                       ]
},
{
        "_id": "63964b3f9677c609e9c81059",
        "name": "Gordon",
        "img": "./assets/gordon.png",
        "votes": [
            {
                "_id": "63c08099b1489ae00cbc00a6",
                "ratingId": "63c08099b1489ae00cbc00a7",
                "createdAt": "2023-01-12T21:50:17.684Z"
            },
            {
                "_id": "63c080a0b1489ae00cbc00aa",
                "ratingId": "63c080a0b1489ae00cbc00ab",
                "createdAt": "2023-01-12T21:50:24.301Z"
            },
]
}
```

I would like to aggregate the total $sum of votes per person in the database.

Here is what I currently have in my controllers.js file:

```
  getAllPersons(req, res) {
    Person.aggregate(
//here is my attempt at aggregating the votes per person 
      [
        { $unwind: "$votes" },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            vote_sum: { $sum: "$votes.rating" },
          },
        },
      ],
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
          res.status(200).send(result);
        }
      }
    );
  },
```

When testing the route in Insomnia I receive the following error:
"ok": 0,
"code": 40324,
"codeName": "Location40324"

Comment: Why are you having a `{ $match: { _id: null } }` stage? Without any projection every documents must have `_id`, that means your `$match` will match no documents and render your remaining pipeline nothing to aggregate.

Comment: I was just experimenting - but I tried with and without the {$match:{_id:null}}  and neither worked.

Comment: And you should be `$unwind: "$votes"` (note the dollar sign) like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/34Fbm2I8C6f)

Comment: Ray, from your suggestions I updated to the following - but it still will not work.

  getAllPersons(req, res) {
    Person.aggregate(
      [{ $sample: { size: 8 } }],
      [
        { $unwind: "$votes" },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: null,
            vote_sum: { $sum: "$votes.rating" },
          },
        },
      ],
      (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          res.status(500).send(err);
        } else {
          res.status(200).send(result);
        }
      }
    );
  },

Comment: your are putting 2 pipelines together (the sample one and the unwind one). Note there are 2 square brackets. Try with keeping either one

Comment: When I remove the $sample aggregation - I receive a 40324 error. It looks like there is still an issue with the vote sum aggregation - but I'm not sure why.

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include your latest attempt? Currently it is very messy to discuss in comments

Comment: question has been updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is already aggregated per person, you just have to sum up the `votes.rating` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      vote_sum: {
        $sum: "$votes.rating"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YG_2pCNP5bQ)